# Can't boot Debian from USB

Tags: debian, kali-linux, system-installation, dd, bootable

I'm having a few problems installing Debian 8.
I created a bootable USB using `dd if=iso-file.iso of=/dev/sdb`, then I changed the BIOS settings to boot from the USB stick, but when I reboot, nothing shows up: the screen becomes black, I don't even get a GRUB menu or anything. I already tried UnetBootin and similar software, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I also tried installing Kali Linux and it gives me the same problem.
I'm running Antergos/Arch Linux.

What am I doing wrong? Do you have any suggestions that might help?

Thank you in advance, Corrado

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the USB stick. They come in a wide range of quality. Have you tried another USB stick?

Comment: Yes, I've ried three USB sticks, but I was able to install other distros from the one I'musing now... @J.P.Petersen

Comment: Please add the output of `fdisk -l` and the exact debian.xyz.iso

Comment: Perhaps a UEFI related problem.  On my system, if I try to boot non UEFI drives, it simply won't boot.

Comment: I suggest erasing the partition first with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M` and run your command. You can use `qemu` to test if your usb is running from your OS: `apt-get install qemu; qemu-system-x86_64 /dev/sdb`